# To pass a value on runtime from HTTPContext as response

Tags: httpcontext

I am trying to pass a value from my HTTP handler module to the redirected response. I am planning to change the view with respect to this value.

```
//HTTPmodule

if (!authorizer.IsAuthorized(controller, action,  context.User))
{
context.Response.Redirect(AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE_URL);
}


AppAccess appAccess = appAuth.GetApplicationAccessStatus("APP1", context.User.Identity.Name.ToString(), avlAccessMode, Edit);
```

**// this where am getting the application access mode**

Depending on the **appAccess**, I need to pass a value as response

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
```

//HTTPModule ends

In the View, with the passed value I need to change the view.

Any idea in passing the value from the HTTP module to view will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Mode", "Read");

I am able to set the value in HTTPModule and the same can be accessible from the view. It worked.

Thanks.